# How to find indexes of a dataframe on the basis of a list of words?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a list:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["like","reduce","carbon","emissions","reduce carbon emissions"],'score': [1,-1,-1,-1,1]})

a = ['like', 'reduce carbon emissions']
```

I would like to find the indexes where the words in `a`are in `b` so that I can sum `score` accordingly.

I am pretty sure this has been asked many times but I can't find any reference.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `isin`

```
b.loc[b.text.isin(a)]
Out[45]: 
                      text  score
0                     like      1
4  reduce carbon emissions      1
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll mark it as correct once SO will allow me to do so